# sectioning wider than text area

Tags: sectioning, scrlayer-scrpage, layout

I stumbled across the type specimen of the beautifull Tierra Nueva and I'm wondering how is it possible to achieve a sectioning in LaTeX similar as shown in the picture (centered and wider than the actual text area). 
Any suggestions (even for Komascript)?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt.a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\title{\null\hss Sehr langer Text der hier stehen soll, ohne wirklich eine Bedeutung zu haben  \hss\null}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\blindtext[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If what you are really referring to is the title, and it's only one line, you could hack it with `{\null\hss ... \hss\null}`

Comment: @barbarabeeton \hss didn't work. Don't know why. Could you please give an example, how to use it?

Comment: The code I gave won't work all by itself; it needs to be taken as an argument: `\title{...}`.  Giving a full example would require knowing what document class you're using.  Inclusion of a small compilable example in a question makes it very much easier for potential helpers to actually help.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I added a MWE to my question.

Comment: Sadly, I'm not a user of the KOMA classes.  If this doesn't work, then someone more relevant knowledge will have to help.  (The technique I suggested ordinarily makes the text look like it has zero width, and centers it.  It will not work directly if the string requires more than one line to fit on the page.  It can be "adjusted" by specifying explicit line breaks with `... \hss\null\\ \null\hss ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can patch `\@maketitle`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{changepage,xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}
 {{\usekomafont{title}{\huge\@title\par}}}
 {\begin{adjustwidth}{-6em}{-6em}\usekomafont{title}{\huge\centering\@title\par}\end{adjustwidth}}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\title{Sehr langer Text der hier stehen soll, ohne wirklich eine Bedeutung zu haben}

\begin{document}

\tracingmacros=1
\maketitle
\tracingmacros=0

\blindtext[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]